# Extract integers enclosed in round brackets

Tags: text-processing, grep

I've a file which contains list of movie names and their release year. I want to list out all release years. Specifically my file looks like below

> ```
> TDKR(2012)    
> Vicky Cristina Barcelona (2008)  
> ...
> ```

I tried grep with regex as follows

```
grep "^.*\\([0-9]*\\)$" movie.txt
```

and it works but it is printing entire line I want only years. Can I do it with `grep`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GNU grep supports an `-o` option which will give you the matching pattern, so you could use `grep -o '([0-9]\+)'` but this will also print the parentheses. For more flexibility and portability, though, you should post-process with `sed`:

```
grep '([0-9]\+)$' movie.txt | sed 's/.*(\([0-9]\+\))$/\1/'
# assumes that the year is always at the end of the line.
```

Comment: Well, `grep` being a subset of `sed`, there's no need for `grep` here (also note that `\+` in sed is not portable nor standard). `sed -n 's/.*(\([0-9]\{1,\}\)).*/\1/p'`. All those assume there's only one occurrence of `(xxx)` per line.

Comment: @sch I don't have it in front of me to test, without grep will this filter out lines that don't match the pattern at all?

Comment: Yes, `-n` is to not print the line by default, and the `p` flag to the `s` command is to print the line when the substitution is successful.

Comment: With GNU grep, you can use Perl regex syntax: `grep -Po '(?<=\()[0-9]+(?=\))'` but it doesn't exactly roll off the tongue.

Answer (score 2):

If the numbers are always the last field, then you can do it with a single awk command.

```
bash$ awk '{gsub(/\(|\)/," "); print $NF};' $file
2012
2008
...
```

Answer (score 2):

With perl:

```
perl -lne 'print for /\((\d+)\)/g'
```